# Firebase SDK doesn't work with iOS 10

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, ios10, podfile

I'm  using `Firebase` in my Xcode project. And I am using cocoapods to install it.

In *Podfile* I've set `platform` to `ios, '9.0'`.

All works correctly in iOS 9.3.3 but when I test my app with iOS 10 , I get lots of errors and the Google Sign-in doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem? 
Can I set multiple *platforms* like `platform:ios, '9.0', '10.0'` in my Podfile?

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm an Italian student

Comment: iOS 10 is not currently supported by Firebase.

Comment: I have used Firebase analytics and database successfully with no issues using anonymous login in iOS 10 with a Swift 3 app.   I specifiy 10.0 in my Podfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple changed the way of working with keychain in iOS 10. To fix this you can simply go to Targets > Capabilities and enable keychain sharing (it enables access to keychain for your app).

Answer (score 1):

**openURL** is Deprecated in iOS10, therefore you have to use the new one.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[.annotation])
}
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, Firebase does not work on iOS 10, neither a device nor a simulator. This is a work in progress, so please stay tuned for updates. You can follow general discussion on Firebase at the firebase-talk group, and the Firebase Blog will have announcements as they occur.